# Считывание текста из файла в java

Tags: java, файлы, текст

Мне нужно считать ***весь*** текст из файла в java.
Я знаю, как можно считывать текст построчно, знаю, как считать байты в массив.
Но здесь так не получается, первый способ очень долгий (~30sec), а второй не подходит так, как не получается считать весь текст, приходится считывать только часть.
`char[] chars=new char[fileInputStream.available()];` не подходит так, как я получаю не количество символов, а количество байтов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java 6**

```
File file = new File("abc.txt");
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

**Java 7**

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("abc.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

или

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("abc.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**Java 8**

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("abc.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Path file = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
```

Или, для использования StreamAPI:

```
Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(file);
```